# In Rpi model 1 After installing when i am running show-devices.js getting error of GLIBC_2.17 not found

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

Hello everyone i have installed node-hid successfully but when i am running it's show-devices.js file i am getting erorr

```
     return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
     Error: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/pi/node_modules/node-hid/build/HID/v0.5.1/Release/node-v46-
    linux-arm/HID.node)

        at Error (native)
        at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/nodhid/nodehid.js:9:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the pre-built binaries served up by `node-hid` via `node-pre-gyp` are compiled on systems that use a newer version of glibc than what your pi has available.

So your options include:

- Upgrade glibc (this typically means upgrading the OS)
- Install the necessary build tools (e.g. `build-essential` in Ubuntu, for gcc, g++, make, etc.) and explicitly compile `node-hid` from source with `npm install --build-from-source node-hid`